# Have an apache user call a script with shell_exec();

Tags: php, apache, permissions, gnupg, shell-exec

**PHP - CentOS - Apache** 
I am trying to allow users to encrypt/decrypt files on my site. I've settled on gpg as the way I'm going to encrypt/decrypt. The problem is that I need to run a shell_exec with the encryption command and it doesn't seem to run when called from the browser. I have tried everything I can think of including giving all the folders and files involved 777 permmission, which feels wrong.
I think I can accomplish this by setting up a cronjob and a queue, but I was hoping someone knows a better solution.

These are the commands that won't run..

```
gpg --yes --passphrase=[Enter your passphrase here] -c filename.txt

gpg --yes --passphrase=[Enter your passphrase here] filename.txt.gpg
```

EDIT: I echoed out the command I was sending to shell_exec and it runs fine from the command line. However it will not run from the browser.

Comment: Please provide the code that you're working with.

Comment: shell_exec( 'gpg --yes --passphrase=userspassphrase -c absolutefilepath );

Comment: No errors, just no results. shell_exec( "echo 'something' > absolutefilepath" );   is also not working when the script is called by a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try full path of gpg like `/usr/bin/gpg --yes --passphrase=[Enter your passphrase here] -c absolute_path_to_file` in shell_exec